# Why does my string.split in Python return unwanted values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

```
MyString = "150 250 400 480"
MyString = MyString.split(" ",2)
print(MyString)
```

When I run it on *spyder*, the program spits out 3 elements:

> ['150', '250', '400 480']

It should just return first **2** elements (as specified):

> ['150', '250']

Why is this happening?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, `['150', '250', '400 480']` is correct,it splitted two times, between 150 and 250, and between 250 and the "400 800". the "400 800" are not splitted.
if you want the first two elements use `splitted[:2]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jonathan, but I did it like you said and it returned just 15.

Comment: you have to combine both: MyString.split(" ",2)[:2]

Comment: The second parameter of the method defines how many splits are done, not how many elements are returned: [`string.split(separator, maxsplit)`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Comment: @GuilhermeMendonça the `[:2]` was meant to be used with `MyString.split(" ",2)`,not with `MyString`. [as `MyString.split(" ",2)[:2]`]

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your answers!